# Registering BroadCastReceiver programmatically

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

Is there any advantage of registering BroadcastReceiver Programattically using registerReceiver() rather then registering in AndroidMenifest.xml

Answer (score 1):

Manifest: - The OS will magically find and instantiate your class if needed, calling the onReceive() method, regardless what the running state of your application was - Your receive will only get called once per broadcast (i.e. You can consider that registering in the manifest is like registering your 'class' for receiving the broadcast - and the broadcast instantiates your class as needed)

Programmatically: - registering in code means that you are registering instances of your class to receive broadcast messages (i.e. if your code is a little sloppy, and you manage to register several times, you will end up with multiple BroadcastReceiver instances all having their onReceive() called for a broadcast - to deregister, you need to deregister the specific BroadcastReceiver instance that you previously registered - if your application gets destroyed by the OS, your onReceive() method will not be called for a broadcast

Comment: So, Registering the BroadCastReceiver in Manifest is best if I want my BroadCastReceiver to run Even if my Application is not running. is that correct?

Comment: exactly
Note that some BroadCastReceiver not fired if you register from manafist like ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED and other can't register programmatically like SMS_RECEIVED and for PHONE_STATE.

Comment: Why BroadCastReceiver not fired for ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED if I register in Menifest.?  and Why I can register SMS_RECEIVED and PHONE_STATE programtically ? are these three only exceptional or some other actions also in the exceptional list?

Comment: this is the olny exceptional cases As Far As i know

Comment: Just now I tried to register SMS_RECEIVED Programattically. It is working fine!!!!!. registerReceiver(new MyBroadcastReceiver(), new IntentFilter("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED") );